# How to find all files that consist only of null bytes (any number of them)

Tags: windows, file-management

I need to find all the files on my HDDd that contains only (any number of) NULL bytes. How can I do it on Windows machine. Or with Linux tools live CD?

---

Background:

Something has malformed a bunch of files on my hard drive. The malformed files:

- have theirs **content replaced with NULL bytes**,
- are exactly the same size as before the malform happen,
- modification time was not altered

This is weird. I have located about 40 of them in a HTML/PHP project directory. I can't determine the date when that happend, but it seems that it was more than a few weeks ago, as all my backups contains those malformed files. 
I haven't notice that because I did not use the local files, and the remote copy on my development server is OK, so the sites I was working on were not affected.

I have already restored those files from latest svn commit, but I do not know which other files are affected.

Comment: you have checked the disk and filesystem health with tools like a SMART analysis too, and chkdsk, right?

Comment: SMART data looks healthy. I have not yet run chkdsk, but I will.

Comment: In fact, chkdsk found some errors. I've rebooted and proceeded with `chkdsk /F`, but I am not sure what was the result. I missed the moment when it finished and system booted back to windows after that. Anyway, I do not trust it and I would like to find all the "NULL files" on my disk.

Comment: You can find the output of the CHKDSKcommand in the Windows Application event log with the Event Viewer. The Source provider is "Wininit" and the EventID is "1001".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the (free) version of TotalCommander and search for all files containing 0x0 ten times for example. Then look in the files what they really contain.

Comment: That almost did the job. I have got thousands of false positives with this. But I have used the RegEx method and searched for `^\x00+$` to make sure that there is at least a whole "line" of nulls, and that not a common pattern. Still, the `^` and `$` chars also mean beginning of file and end of file, so the regexp matched the malformed files.

Comment: After the night search, it seems that there is no more malformed files other than those 40 I have identified earlier. Thanks for suggestion. I have forgot about Total Commander.

Comment: @SWilk My solution was to write a custom tool that'd recursively look inside all files under a directory and its subdirectories and list files that had more than 5% of null bytes or files with 5 megabytes or more of zero bytes in content. This is fairly easy to do in Java.

Comment: I could write that without any problem, but I try to check if there is something ready before I make my own solution. I am a little bit to lazy, I think ;)

Answer (score 4):

I had the very same problem.
I wonder that the RegEx in TotalCommander worked for SWilk, as TC does not support \0 in RegEx search according to their own support forum:
http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=26512
(and it did not work for me).

I ended up using grepWin:
http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html

Use "RegEx Search", Search Pattern "\A\0+\Z" and make sure to check the limits (default is not include binaries and files larger than 2000 KB)

Comment: Hi, I have accepted the answer, because at that time I thought that it worked, but only the files I have already restored were affected, so there was nothing more malformed. I did not notice that \0 does not work.
Anyway, I did not find any other malformed file. 
I still can't think of any reason what might have malformed my files.

Comment: @SWilk I can already guess that the program which NULL'ified a bunch of your files is NotePad++.  It's an absolute abomination that destroys entire files for no apparent reason.  There has been hundreds of users complaining about this exact thing randomly (and very rarely) occurring to them and yet, in 2021 it is still not completely solved, tough on forums it is said to occur much, much less than a few years ago.  This occurred to me also after 6 years of using NotePad++ and now I only use it paired with an instant mirror/backup solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with a power shell script. It may not be the most elegant way to code it but it works. It will list any file with no contents or where the contents contains only null values. the -TotalCount value can be removed or changed to read the whole file or more lines. My initial thoughts were if their was a line feed then the contents are not just nulls.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\somepath\tostartfrom -Recurse -File
foreach ($f in $files){
    $content = Get-Content -Path $f.FullName -TotalCount 10
    if ($content -match '[\\x01-\\xFF]+') { 
        #do nothing as file has a valid character in it
    }
    else {Write-Output $f.FullName}
}
Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
```