# What could cause the files to be replaced with null bytes, size and timestamp not modified?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystems

Something has malformed a bunch of files on my hard drive. The malformed files:

- have theirs **content replaced with NULL bytes**,
- are exactly the same size as before the malform happen,
- modification time was not altered

I have at least 40 of those malformed files and are looking for other victims. Most of the files are part of Netbeans php project. Some were text files, some were images. None of them was modified lately. HDD Smart does not show anything worrying and AV software did not detect any viruses. My OS is Windows 7.

Any ideas what could cause this strange behaviour?

[EDIT]
I have scanned the disk to find other malformed files, and the wierd thing is, there are no other "NULLed" files than those 40 I have found earlier. All the files belonged to the same Netbeans project. I have never seen something similar before.

Comment: Although you got the all clear from HDD Smart this really sounds like HDD corruption. Make sure you have a backup regardless.

Comment: I do make daily backup with Duplicati, but those 40 files was used so rarely, that they made it unnoticed for at least two months, so they are malformed in my oldest backups. Fortunatelly, they also have remote copy on my development server (via upload on save in netbeans), and those copies were correct, so I have all the files.

Comment: Apart from the reason, I am looking for [a way to find all the files which are similarily malformed](http://superuser.com/questions/845268/how-to-find-all-files-that-consist-only-of-null-bytes-any-number-of-them)

Comment: I think you need to create a new question to find a tool that will identify any file containing nothing but null bytes.

Comment: This sounds like a crash during defragmentation.

Comment: Had similar issue on a production environment that host millions of files. We still don't know from where it came from.

Comment: We're experiencing the same in our production environment. At random times we end up with file that looks OK based on metadata (size, modified time, name ++) but only contains 0-bytes. It seems to happen as the computer e.g. loses power.

Comment: Could it be that you're experiencing the problem explained in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52751216/930546

Answer (score 5):

A [discussion on the SyncTrayzor github](https://github.com/canton7/SyncTrayzor/issues/471) shows that it might be related to windows update.

It has happened to me twice that the `config.xml` from SyncTrayzor was filled with null-bytes after a windows update and at least one other user had the same problem. Also some Firefox cache files were null-filled at about the same moment.

Searching for files with just null-bytes seem to indicate that they are mostly things like 'configuration' files, or cache files or something. My hypothesis is that these were kept open when the computer was forced to reboot as part of the windows update and were not synced correctly to the drive.

Edit:
Checking [restart history](https://serverfault.com/questions/702828/windows-server-restart-shutdown-history) and [update history](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5472-view-windows-update-history-windows-10-a.html) indicates that

- Almost all 100% null-byte files are created on the same day as a reboot. Only a few specific ones are not.
- The majority of them were create on, or the day after, a 'Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1803'. Maybe the reboot is occasionally postponed to the day after the install?

So it seems clear that the creation of null-bytes is triggered by reboots.
Most reboots where probably because of an update, so unclear whether it can happen with any reboot or whether update-reboots are special in this regard.

I have not yet figured out how to get all the information in a machine readable form, so it's an inefficient manual investigation so far. Most of these screens I can't even copy-paste from, so this is very inefficient. I would be grateful if someone knows how to get this information into files:

- File names and creation/modification dates of files with all bytes null.
- Windows shutdown/startup dates. Edit: `get-eventlog system | Where source -eq EventLog | Where InstanceID -like 214748965*`
- Windows update dates (specifically the ones requiring a reboot).

Edit: Reboot-hypothesis corroborated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/52751216/2097 . That answer only refers to unexpected reboots though.

Edit: Reboot-hypothesis corroborated by N++ team: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/13302/fix-corrupted-txt-file-null

Possible recovery mechanism using Recuva: [Recover file corrupted due to power cut off](https://superuser.com/questions/377904/recover-file-corrupted-due-to-power-cut-off)

Comment: PowerShell's Format-Hex (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex?view=powershell-7) might help detect which files have only null bytes. Maybe make a batch file to get the Format-Hex output of the files into txt files, then parse the txt files to remove all null characters, resulting in 0-byte txt files (which indicate which files are null bytes only). Once you know which files are null characters only, Windows dir command will tell you date modified or created (see "dir /?" for help). wmic, although crappy, could also help list file metadata.

Comment: I just lost Synctrayzor's config.xml to null bytes after I powered on the laptop, it seemed to work and then did something weird and went black, and I powered on again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue with VSCode. A big chunk of my opened but inactive GIT repo was corrupted like that.
There was no crash and the issue occurred in the middle of work:

I've committed and pushed some files, then found a typo and wanted to amend the commit. That's then I got the error message (about a different worktree).
There was no reboot between the working time and the corrupted time. And only couple of minutes has passed.

```
git commit --amend
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
error: bad ref for pipelines/.git/worktrees/pipelines_worktree4/logs/HEAD
error: bad ref for pipelines/.git/logs/HEAD
error: bad ref for A:/_All/My.Work/2018.Google/pipelines/.git/worktrees/pipelines_worktree4/logs/HEAD
error: bad ref for pipelines/.git/logs/HEAD
error: bad signature 0x00000000
fatal: index file corrupt
fatal: failed to run repack
```

I've found a thread in VScode repo regarding this kind of corruption:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9589

**Update**: Or maybe this has happened couple of months ago and GIT only discovered it now when it tried to do garbage collection.